# Filter Time in Column

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have tried multiple possible solutions here, but still having some trouble filtering one column based on time. I used lubridate to turn the column into hms. Please advise. New to R, so apologize if this seems redundant.

I have tried the filter command and that doesn't seem to work because the data type is wrong. Character vs double. I think the double came in because of the lubridate code, but I could be wrong here. Code sample below for relevant section.

here is the top of the dataset for reference.

```
> head(iislog1,n=10)
      iisdate    iistime                                 csUriStem timeTaken
1  2019-05-10 4H 35M 10S                              /claraportal      7375
2  2019-05-10 4H 35M 11S                              /claraportal       484
3  2019-05-10 4H 35M 11S                              /claraportal       468
4  2019-05-10 4H 35M 13S                              /claraportal      1024
5  2019-05-10 4H 35M 54S                              /claraportal      5765
6  2019-05-10 4H 35M 57S               /claraportal/content/bundle      2019
7  2019-05-10 4H 35M 57S   /claraportal/dashboard.fwk.style/bundle      2019
8  2019-05-10 4H 35M 57S /claraportal/bundle/css/modules/2019v1_v1      2238
9  2019-05-10 4H 35M 57S           /claraportal/scripts/thirdparty      2457
10 2019-05-10 4H 35M 58S               /claraportal/content/bundle       921


#change data type for date and time columns
iislog$iisdate <- ymd(iislog$iisdate)
iislog$iistime <- hms(iislog$iistime)
#create subset of the original data
iislog1 <- iislog %>% select(iisdate,iistime,csUriStem,timeTaken)
#ensure the csUriStem column is in all lowercase. This is because the URLs
#seem to have mixed case and therefore can show up moe than once.
iislog1$csUriStem <- tolower(iislog1$csUriStem)
#filter the rows to find times between
iislog1 <- filter(iislog1$iistime > '04:40:59' & iislog1$iistime < '21:38:37')

> iislog1 <- filter(iislog1$iistime > '04:40:59' & iislog1$iistime < '21:38:37')
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "logical"
```

Comment: Currently you are comparing date class with a string, convert your date/time string into date class.

Comment: To state zx8754's point another way: `iislog1$iistime` might be class `datetime`, but `'04:40:59'` is just a `character`

Comment: Actually, `iislog$iistime` after conversion `iislog$iistime <- hms(iislog$iistime)` is class `Period` (see `??hms`). So for comparison convert your time string to `hms()`:`iislog1.filtered <- filter(iislog1, iistime > hms('04:35:10') & iistime < hms('21:38:37'))`

Comment: I will try that. So, basically, what you are saying is that there was no point in even converting it to hms? If I had just kept the initial data, which was probably character, I would have been fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to get proper formating:

```
iislog1$dtime <- with( iislog1, strptime(paste( iisdate,iistime),
                                         format="%Y-%m-%d %HH %MM %SS"))
```

I don't think your input format is close enough to any typical protocol to be accepted by the `hms` function. Base R is more "complete".

Then use a proper "datetime" value for comparison. Or if you want a time range regardless of the date, use `format` to return just the times and do an alpha comparison. In your instance, an alpha comparison of '21:38:37' with  '4:40:59' would show that the former was "less than" the latter since the leading letters were "4" and "2". The formatted version of '4:40:59' in a correctly constructed R datetime would be '04:40:59'.

Answer (score 0):

You just didn't pass an dataframe to be filtered, you passed a vector. Note the difference

```r
# failes
iislog1 <- filter(iislog1$iistime > '04:40:59' & iislog1$iistime < '21:38:37')

# works   |--missing--|   
iislog1 <- iislog1 %>% filter(iislog1$iistime > '04:40:59' & iislog1$iistime < '21:38:37')
```

The `tidyverse` shines for being less verbose than base R. The big savings are in the piping and not having to name the dataframe each time (ie. `df$col`). You *can* but you need to pass it something first for example you can't do

```
df %>% filter(df$col < 2)
```

but this by itself

```
filter(df$col < 2)
```

This is because all of the `dplyr` verbs expect the first argument to be the thing to pipe and then return a dataframe. These three things are the same

```
filter(df, col < 2)
df %>% filter(., col < 2)
df %>% filter(col < 2)
```

So `filter()` was expecting a dataframe and you passed it a vector `df$col` and it didn't know what to do. I hope this explanation makes sense. The R for Data Science book is a great resource for this and free online.

All in all, the best way to do all of your steps would be something like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)


raw_data <-
  tibble(
    iisdate = "2019-05-10",
    iistime = paste0(1:23, "H 35M 11S"),
    csUriStem = "/ClaraPortal",
    timeTaken = 7375,
    a_column_you_dont_need = "a",
    another_one = "b"
  ) 


iislog <-
  raw_data %>% 
  mutate(
    iisdate = ymd(iisdate),
    iistime = hms(iistime),
    csUriStem = tolower(csUriStem)
  ) %>% 
  select(iisdate:timeTaken) %>% 
  filter(iistime > hms("04:40:59"), iistime < hms("21:38:37"))
```